# android set app shortcut

Tags: android, shortcut

I want to know if it is possible(and if it is, how can I do it) to automatically add a shortcut of my app on the user screen. Eg when I am pressing a button from my app, to automatically set a shortcut on user screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't think that is was possible but it turns out it is: [adding shortcut to homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307826/adding-his-application-to-the-add-to-home-screen-shortcut-section) and [LauncherShortcut from the API demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/LauncherShortcuts.html) pretty cool

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
private void addShortcut() {

    Intent addIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world));
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.drawable.ic_action_search));
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext(),OtherActivity.class));
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

and also you need some permissions in your menifest,like this:

```
<uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission 
        android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```